Laravel sail can't connect to mysql with third party app
I've created a new laravel app with sail as the documentation described using:
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
My .env file looks like this:
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=rebrickable
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password

When I try to connect with third party app I get this message:


The hosts are different. User sail is on 172.19.0.1 but you have given 127.0.0.1 as host
